# Font Awesome in CSS content not rendering on mobile

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Here is a basic example of Font Awesome integration as a CSS content pseudo element:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li:before {
  content: '\f105';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Another item</li>
  <li>Yet another item</li>
</ul>
```

External URL to test: https://jsfiddle.net/1zknmxLg/2/

Everything works as it used to work with previous version of Font Awesome, however this one doesn't render the icons on any mobile phone (tested on iPhone 7 and latest Android). Why is this?

Comment: Font Awesome v 5 right ?

Comment: @Anuresh, yes the latest version.

Comment: am pretty sure the font-family is wrong

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I am not sure why it works on the desktop then.

Comment: check the JS fiddle, you are include the CSS as a script

Comment: @TemaniAfif, you were right, it's the font family. I guess it worked for me because JS Fiddle and SO also use the old version.

Comment: @sdvnksv Hi just updated your fiddle. It seems like you didn't added FontAwesome library to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After going through the documentation, the correct usage is:

```
li:after {
    content: '\f105';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

If you used a paid (pro) version, replace Free by Pro (or Brand). `font-weight: 900;` stands for solid icons.

Answer (score 2):

Try this  `font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li:before {
  content: "\f105";
  font-family: Font Awesome\ 5 Free;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
li {
 font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5SOiIsAziJl6AWe0HWRKTXlfcSHKmYV4RBF18PPJ173Kzn7jzMyFuTtk8JA7QQG1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Another item</li>
  <li>Yet another item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just checked the Font Awesome CSS and they seem to have a bunch of those font families now. Unexpected!

Comment: No idea why, but the backslash in the font name solved my issue.  The icons wouldn't render on any mobile browsers, but worked great on desktop browsers.